# Removing user contact methods works from functions.php but not from a plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, filters, users

I'd like to remove user fields and I used this code:

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'newfields' );
function newfields( $user_contact ) {
    unset($user_contact['facebook']);
    unset($user_contact['twitter']);

    return $user_contact;
 }
```

If I use this code in `functions.php` of my theme, it works, but if I use this code in a plugin, it doesn't work.

Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Did you try playing with the filter priority?

Comment: I hadn't thought. It is the easiest thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the matter of adjusting the *priority* of your filter callback,
since the plugins files are executed before the `functions.php` theme file. That could explain why it works in your `functions.php` file, if the priority is the same.

When you add the code snippet to a plugin, it might be executed before the other plugins that use the same filter.

The default priority is `10`, so you should try something higher in your plugin code, for example:

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'newfields', 99 );
```

or even

```
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'newfields', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

if you want to be absolutely sure your filter callback is the last one to be executed - assuming the other plugins are not using `PHP_INT_MAX` as well.

But better yet, just check the priority the `user_contactmethods` filter callbacks the other plugins are using.

Comment: Great, it can be a fun game to play, to find the correct priority of a filter/action ;-)