# WordPress 4.0 beta - how to change the link URL in RSS feeds

Tags: permalinks, rss, feed

I am using WP 4 beta and have a site at blah.com/blog but I display the posts on my site at blah.com/articles

I want all of the URLs in my RSS feed to use my site URL.
Following what was mentioned here: [Change the link URL in default RSS feeds](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96602/change-the-link-url-in-default-rss-feeds)

I added this filter to the bottom of plugin.php (add_filter doesn't work in functions.php in 4 beta because it's defined in plugin.php which is loaded after functions.php, I found out)

```
add_filter( 'the_permalink_rss', 'wpse_96602_change_feed_item_url' );

function wpse_96602_change_feed_item_url( $url )
{
return str_replace('/blog/','/article/',$url);
}
```

But this hasn't worked. What do I need to do?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe you can do similar as discussed in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156730/removing-user-contact-methods-works-from-functions-php-but-not-from-a-plugin/156731#156731) ?

Comment: It's not clear why doesn't WP just generate correct links, which probably has something to do with how you changed URL structure?.. Also I don't follow what exactly your issue with priorities. If this is resolved please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: It was because my blog is at blah.com/blog but I use the WP API to actually display blog posts on another page on my site. Setting the priority of the filter to PHP_INT_MAX fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because my blog is at blah.com/blog but I use the WP API to actually display blog posts on another page on my site. Setting the priority of the filter to PHP_INT_MAX fixed the problem.